# rsyslog configuration without restart

Tags: systemd, logs, services, rsyslog, aws

I have a problem with logging. 
With my configuration below, I have to perform rsyslog restart if I want to have my application log file in /var/log. Also, I have to restart rsyslog it in case of log rotate.
What is the proper configuration of rsyslog and systemd service to avoid rsyslog restart?

My configuration:
/etc/rsyslog.d/myapp.conf

```
if $programname == 'myapp' then {
    /var/log/myapp/myapp.log
    stop
}
```

/etc/systemd/system/myapp.service

```
[Unit]
Description=myapp

[Service]
User=myapp
ExecStart=/usr/bin/myapp
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=myapp

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/logrotate.d/myapp.conf

```
/var/log/myapp/myapp.log {
  rotate 7
  daily
  size 100MB
  compress
  missingok
  notifempty
  postrotate
    sudo systemctl restart rsyslog.service
  endscript
}
```

Comment: why do you have to restart rsyslog? you may need to restart/reload only the application, rsyslog will handle logrotation fine

Comment: this is the problem. without rsyslog restart logs file are not created

Comment: Paweł, that's really weird.. are you sure your app is configured to log to the file? from systemd unit it seems it logs to syslog, not particular file.. can you post more information on how the app is configured internally for logging? do you have a redirect in rsyslog for the app?

Comment: according to my knowledge - configuration is ok. stdout stderr goes to syslog, then in rsyslog.config is a redirection to file. But everything requires rsyslog restart

Comment: did you try using `copytruncate` in logrotate unit configuration and/or `create` to create an empty file after rotation?

Comment: I've changed log rotation to:
```
/var/log/myapp/myapp.log {
  rotate 7
  daily
  size 100k
  compress
  missingok
  notifempty
  copytruncate
}
```
according to u comment Bart and works perfectly. 
so the my last problem is - i still have to restart rsyslog before my service start

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to tell rsyslogd to reopen the log-files with something like:

```
/usr/bin/systemctl kill -s HUP rsyslog.service
```

I have not yet found how to make it reload its configuration, most hits says you need to restart it to apply new configuration.

I found this serverfault question that links information it is **not possible**: 
https://serverfault.com/q/1053728/343786

And these posts that tells a little about **why** it is not possible:
https://rainer.gerhards.net/2008/10/new-rsyslog-hup-processing.html 
https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/3759

The later refer to RELP that could be used to avoid loosing log messages during restart, see: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliable_Event_Logging_Protocol

Comment: The 2008 gerhards.net blog post you link (from the rsyslogd lead) says that SIGHUP, by default, **does** reload the configuration. However, [this](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/compatibility/v4compatibility.html#hup-processing) says that this behavior was deprecated in v4, and will go away in v5.

Comment: @DanielGriscom  That blog-post is 15 years old, the default have changed, RSyslog is currently at version 8. Besides, the "full restart" he mentions included a loss of service similar to doing a systemctl restart.

Comment: Then you may want to clarify your answer, which misrepresents what the blog post states.